# webview not loading particular url

Tags: android, url, webview

this is my [URL](http://api.tixbag.com/test.php)

I am trying to load this url in webview but it's not loading.this `URL` is perfectlly run on web browser.

webview only don't load this `URL`.

This is my code

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient(this));
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            if (Utils.isSameDomain(postUrl, url)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("postUrl", url);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                openInAppBrowser(url);
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
    webView.clearCache(true);
    webView.clearHistory();
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getPointerCount() > 1) {
                return true;
            }
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    m_downX = event.getX();
                }
                break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                    event.setLocation(m_downX, event.getY());
                }
                break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you have done so far? Please share code, and what error message you are getting?

Comment: post you code what you are done so far

Comment: i am not getting any error if i change my url it's work fine it's not load only this url

Comment: use http://www before your URL  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewController());

        webView.loadUrl("http://api.tixbag.com/test.php");


    }
    public class WebViewController extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: there is no need for other settings, only enabling javascript can work

Comment: @miteshmakwana happy to help u enjoy coding

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to load Url

```
public class TestingActivity extends AppCompatActivity
 {

    private WebView mWebview;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mWebview = new WebView(this);

        mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript

        final Activity activity = this;

        mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest req, WebResourceError rerr) {
                // Redirect to deprecated method, so you can use it in all SDK versions
                onReceivedError(view, rerr.getErrorCode(), rerr.getDescription().toString(), req.getUrl().toString());
            }
        });

        mWebview.loadUrl("http://api.tixbag.com/test.php");
        setContentView(mWebview);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just load your http://api.tixbag.com/test.php in my webView by enabling javascript just before loading url.

**Sample code:**

```
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

mWebView.loadUrl("http://api.tixbag.com/test.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

this maybe comes from cookies.

add this before initializing the webview.

```
CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
```